# Keras plot the units during learning

Tags: keras, regression

You can view a neural network as a tool that tries to learn "basis functions" (i.e. last hidden units) and then recombines then into a function approximation of the "true" function. I want to visualize this process during learning, and in order to do that, I would need to plot the behaviour of the hidden units at (say) every epoch during training and visualize how they change. How can one do this using Keras? Ideally, I do not want to have to fully rewrite the "fit" procedure but I am willing to do this if needed.